# how to add new functions to a class whose implementation is not accessible in c++

Tags: c++

Is it possible to add new functions in the class if the implementation of this class is hidden to user.
But still if its required to add a new function to this class.

Comment: Derive a new class from it, add new methods to that class?

Comment: Probably an XY problem - why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern

Answer (score 8):

"Is it possible to add new functions in the class if the implementation of this class is hidden" - In general, No.

To add new functions you have some options:

1) Get hold of the original source code and add your function (best option).

2) Derive from the class (if it is not `final`) and add your function (only good enough if you can then use the derived type everywhere needed).

3) Write a free function that takes a pointer or reference to an instance of the class and then uses that to access (`public`) members of the class. Not really like adding a real member, but in some cases good enough.

You cannot dynamically add functions to a class in C++ like you can in some other languages.

Answer (score -2):

> Is it possible to add new functions in the class if the implementation of this class is hidden

Yes, you can add new functions to the class declaration.  C++ does not demand that all member functions are implemented in the same compilation unit.

Adding `virtual` functions or member variables could be a problem, if the class is instantiated in code that was compiled with the 'old' class declaration.